# Could not determine Java version, Android Studio, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle, version-control, ubuntu-14.04

When importing a project from Git VCS, Android Studio downloads it and then asks to import the project from Gradle.  I choose "Use default gradle wrapper" and it seems like it's working but then I get an error "Could not determine Java version".  I'm using Oracle Java 8, it's clearly being pointed to in the Android Studio config.  Could it be talking about the version used in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.  I wasn't paying attention.  The JDK location was pointing to a different version of java (java-gcj-4.8) instead of java-8-oracle.